# How to get single value from request response

Tags: javascript, request, response

I started writing a program that will automate user actions, by now it's meant to be an easier menu to make faster actions by just sending requests to the official website by clicks on my own page. (something like web-bot but not exactly).
My problem is when i send **login request** in response i get back user_id, server, **session_id** etc. And I need to save that session_id to make the other actions.
How can i save this to variable.
All in JavaScript.

I was looking in the internet since yesterday for an answer and i still can't find (or understand) how to get this
I tried
`function login(){ fetch('url', { method: 'POST', headers: { //headers }, body: //my Id's }) })`

//There's the problem to solve
`.then(res => res.text()) .then(data => obj = data) .then(() => console.log(obj)) console.log(body.session_id);`

// I even tried the substring but 1. It won't work as I want because There are sometimes //more and less letters. 2. I get and error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading //'substr')"

```
`session = obj;
session_id = session.substring(291,30)
console.log(session_id)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) method on the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object returned from `fetch()`, which will give you a string representation of the response.

You probably want to be using the [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method instead, and from that you can get your `session_id`.

This guide has some more useful information that may help you: https://javascript.info/fetch

Comment: I did something like this now

`async function login( url ){
let session = await fetch(

})
let result = await session.json();
alert(result.message);`

**And in the window i get only "Undefined".** 
Before i set the whole function with async method it was calling an error that "session.json is not a function"

Comment: Ok i changed the last line from alert to console.log(result) and now i have these objects in console, so it just  may be not working in the alert window. Now I want to get the session_id from data -> user -> session_id:  "*id*"

Answer (score 1):

Ok it works now with

```
`async function login(){ let session = await fetch('url', {
    //code
}
let result = await session.json();
console.log(result);
session_id = result.data.user.session_id;
user_id = result.data.user.id;`
```

Comment: If my solution helped, please mark the question as solved! Glad you got it working

Comment: I can't give upvote ( I created my account right before post) so i will give the green mark as solved because I inspired the ways to solve from the link you sent. Thanks!